# obtener 2 objetos de un listado a la vez mediante un for

Tags: python, django, bucle-for

Alguien me puede ayodar a implementar un for en python donde necesito ir obteniendo en vez de la primera posicion de una lista, la primera y la segunda luego la tercera y cuarta y asi sucesivamente ? .
Por ejemplo asi tengo mi codigo:
for var in variables :
....resto de codigo
pero ahi solo toma de una en una necesito ir obteniendo el valor de 2 .
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español. Este tipo de preguntas no son muy bien recibidas. Lo mejor es que coloques el código con un mínimo ejemplo de lo que has intentado. Saludos. [Cómo preguntar: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask]

Comment: No veo que tiene esta pregunta relacionado con django, igual deberías eliminar esa etiqueta.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes hacerlo usando:

```
lista = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
for i,k in zip(lista[0::2], lista[1::2]):
    print("i =",str(i),", k =",str(k))  

# Salida
# i = 1 , k = 2
# i = 3 , k = 4
# i = 5 , k = 6
# i = 7 , k = 8
```

Comment: Gracias me es de mucha ayuda

Comment: @DarianGarciaMejias Si la pregunta te ha sido útil y consideras que es correcta puedes aceptarla: [https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers].

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que quieres es que solamente te devuelva parejas de dos en dos, es decir que si la lista tiene elementos impares pierda el último, te valdría la respuesta de Jaime. Otra manera de hacer lo mismo podría ser:

```
lista = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

print(list(zip(lista[::2], lista[1::2]))) 
# Devuelve [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8)]
```

Si no quieres que el último elemento desaparezca:

```
print([lista[a:a+2] for a in range(0,len(lista),2)])
# Devuelve [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Solo como curiosidad, la documentación del módulo `itertools` contiene al final un apartado de [recetas](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) en el que aparece esta pequeña joya:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
```

Puedes copiar esa receta en tu código y usarlo así:

```
lista = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
for x,y in grouper(lista, 2):
  print(x,y)
```

Produce:

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 None
```

Observa que si el número de elementos en la lista es impar, rellena por defecto la última pareja con `None`. Puedes especificar otro valor en el parámetro `fillvalue`.

La ventaja de esta solución con respecto a otras basadas en slices, es que ésta funciona también aún si el iterable no soporta indexación. Por ejemplo, si tu lista no es una lista sino un objeto `range()`, o un fichero, éste tipo de objetos son iterables, pero no admiten una sintaxis como `objeto[::2]`. Aún así funcinoan con este `grouper()`:

```
for x,y in grouper(range(5), 2):
  print(x,y)
---
0 1
2 3
4 None
```